# why TCP window scale values (scaling factor) are different in different hosts?

Tags: networking, tcp

why TCP window scale values (scaling factor)  are different in different hosts?

why not make this value the same on all hosts?

in theory, this value is between 0-14. what is the practical range for the scale value in today's Internet?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 1323, section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323#section-2):

> The maximum receive window, and therefore the scale factor, is
> determined by the maximum receive buffer space.  In a typical
> modern implementation, this maximum buffer space is set by default
> but can be overridden by a user program before a TCP connection is
> opened.  This determines the scale factor, [...]

Answer (score -1):

Since the max window is 2^S (where S is the scaling shift count)
times at most 2^16 - 1 (the maximum unscaled window), the maximum
window is guaranteed to be < 2^30 if S <= 14.  Thus, the shift
count must be limited to 14 (which allows windows of 2^30 = 1
Gbyte).  If a Window Scale option is received with a shift.cnt
value exceeding 14, the TCP should log the error but use 14
instead of the specified value.

RFC 1323

Comment: you are pointing to rfc 1323 have your answer referenced content?